# RecyclerView error: No adapter attached; skipping layout?

Tags: android

I am fetching data from **TMDB** API.

I am getting

> error:RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Right now, I am getting data via **`Retrofit`**.

Can anybody help me?

`Adapter` code is bellow:

```
    public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieDetailActivity.MovieViewHolder> {

    private List<Reviews> rReviewList;
    private LayoutInflater rInflater;
    private Context rContext;

    public ReviewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.rContext = context;
        this.rInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.rReviewList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public MovieDetailActivity.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View view = rInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_review, parent, false);
        return new MovieDetailActivity.MovieViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieDetailActivity.MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Reviews reviews = rReviewList.get(position);
        Picasso.with(rContext)
                .load(reviews.getUrl())

                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Perform click
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rReviewList.size();
    }

    //To update data
    public void setReviewList(List<Reviews> reviewsList) {
        this.rReviewList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.rReviewList.addAll(reviewsList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

`MovieDetailsActivity` is where I want to fetch review data

Its code is below:

```
public class MovieDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MOVIE = "EXTRA_MOVIE";
    private Movie mMovie;
    private Reviews mReviews;
    private Genres mGenres;
    public ReviewAdapter rAdapter;


    //private MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter rAdapter;
    ImageView backdrop;
    ImageView poster;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    TextView releaseDate;
    TextView voteAverage;
    RecyclerView reviews;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE)) {
            mMovie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Detail activity must receive a movie parcelable");
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        toolbarLayout.setTitle(mMovie.getTitle());

        //ucitavanje adaptera

        reviews = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reviewList);

        reviews.setAdapter(rAdapter);
        rAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this);
        getReviews(mMovie.getId());

        backdrop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_description);
        releaseDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_date);
        voteAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
        //genres = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genresArray);


        title.setText(mMovie.getTitle());
        description.setText(mMovie.getDescription());
        voteAverage.setText(mMovie.getVoteAverage());
        releaseDate.setText(mMovie.getReleaseDate());


        poster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        String internetUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(mMovie.getPoster())
                .override(800, 890)
                .into(poster);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(mMovie.getBackdrop())
                .into(backdrop);
    }


    private void getReviews(String id) {
        RestAdapter.getMovieService().getReviews(id, new Callback<ReviewWraper>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ReviewWraper reviewWraper, Response response) {
                rAdapter.setReviewList(reviewWraper.getResults());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        });
    }

    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;

        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture_review);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/edit this lines

```
reviews = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reviewList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        reviews.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
      rAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this);
        reviews.setAdapter(rAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create the adapter, Use this:

```
rAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this);
reviews.setAdapter(rAdapter);
```

Instead

```
reviews.setAdapter(rAdapter);
    rAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this);
```

Remember, your Recycler view requires a LayoutManager, something like this:

```
reviews.setLayoutManager(
    new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```